# How to prevent ClearDB (MySQL) from dropping when heroku puts my app to sleep

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, heroku, cleardb

I have deployed a Spring Boot app on heroku and installed ClearDB addon which is just MySQL database. I am using free plan so I don't mind that my app is going to sleep after an hour of inactivity but I have one issue - database drops after app is going to sleep. I am wondering if that's just how heroku works when using free service or if it can be changed in heroku settings.

I am using auto ddl set to `create` in my `application.properties`, can it be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That behaviour is caused by your `application.properties`, it's not related to Heroku.
You should change it to `update` instead of `create` because with create the database schema will be dropped and created afterwards.
More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/what-are-the-possible-values-of-the-hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-configuration-and-wha)